# Undefined name 'changeButton'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dev/utils/routes.dart';


 class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  bool changeButton = false;

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}


 class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  get name => null;



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Image.asset(
                "assets/images/login_image.png",
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              Text(
                "Welcome",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 28,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),

              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 32.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Enter username",
                        labelText: "Username",
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        satState() {}
                      },
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      obscureText: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Enter Password",
                        labelText: "Password",
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40.0,
                    ),
                    
                    InkWell(
                     onTap: (){
                       setState(() {
                         changeButton = true;
                       });
                      //  Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyRoutes.homeRoute);
                     },
                      child: AnimatedContainer(
                        duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                        width: 150,
                        height: 40,
                        
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text(
                          "login",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, 
                            fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                             fontSize: 18
                             ),  
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.deepPurple,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
                          )
                        ),
                    )

                         
                    // ElevatedButton(
                    //   child: Text("Login"),
                    //   style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    //     minimumSize: Size(140, 40),
                    //   ),
                    //   onPressed: () {
                    //     Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyRoutes.homeRoute);
                    //   },
                    // ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Error:

[image]

Undefined name 'changeButton'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name

Please fix this problem

Comment: instead of image please share code.

Answer (score 2):

Define a new variable changebutton before class declaration or inside _LoginPageState

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dev/utils/routes.dart';


 class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  // bool changeButton = false; //remove this outside the class or inside _LoginPageState 

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}


 class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  get name => null;
 bool changeButton = false; 


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Image.asset(
                "assets/images/login_image.png",
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              Text(
                "Welcome",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 28,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),

              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 32.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Enter username",
                        labelText: "Username",
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        satState() {}
                      },
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      obscureText: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Enter Password",
                        labelText: "Password",
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40.0,
                    ),
                    
                    InkWell(
                     onTap: (){
                       setState(() {
                         changeButton = true;
                       });
                      //  Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyRoutes.homeRoute);
                     },
                      child: AnimatedContainer(
                        duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                        width: 150,
                        height: 40,
                        
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text(
                          "login",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, 
                            fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                             fontSize: 18
                             ),  
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.deepPurple,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
                          )
                        ),
                    )

                         
                    // ElevatedButton(
                    //   child: Text("Login"),
                    //   style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    //     minimumSize: Size(140, 40),
                    //   ),
                    //   onPressed: () {
                    //     Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyRoutes.homeRoute);
                    //   },
                    // ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`changeButton` declare under `_LoginPageState`

```
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  get name => null;
 bool changeButton = false;
```

Another approch :

```
widget.changeButton = true;
```

Comment: no .. not work..

Comment: What was the error?

Answer (score 0):

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}


 class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  get name => null;
  bool changeButton = false;
....
}
```

or

use `widget` like widget.changeButton = true

Comment: Try correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named 'changeButton'.
                         changeButton = true;
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: `changeButton` can't throw such an error with this code example

Comment: Are you trying to pass the value of a variable to a constructor?